# How do I create an app in Facebook that will force users to like a page in order to use it?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to replicate the functionality of the page below where there are two tabs (Lady Gaga and Enrique Iglesias) which force users to like a page before they are able to use the app. With the latest Facebook changes is it still possible to be done? I am in the process of building my first app have been googling for the past week and have not gotten anywhere. I am literally pulling my hair :(. I hope somebody can help.
Thanks in advance,

http://www.facebook.com/2DayFM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this can be done is by inspecting the signed_request http post parameter in server side code that Facebook sends your site when it loads your page.  Here is an example of how to do it in [PHP](http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php), although its basically the same process in whatever language you know.

Answer (score 1):

It is a violation of Facebook's Platform Policies to incentivize the "Like" action. See https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration

Comment: You mean, you **aren't allowed**. Technically it would be possible, I think.

Comment: Correct. Edited to reflect this.

Comment: Now it's ok apparently. "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, like your app’s Page, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions. " (From your link, @JoshEnders.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an FQL query on the connection table to do this.

```
select target_id from connection where source_id = 297200003 and target_id = 1024709214
```

To do an FQL query you can use [FB.Data.Query](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Data.query/) or you can test it on command line using cURL. You need to pass the access_token for the user.

```
curl "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=selecn+where+source_id=297200003+and+target_id=1024709214&access_token=..."
```

Comment: The answer from OffBySome worked perfectly but thanks for your help. I ended up looking at FQL and it seems like a great tool to use for my projects. Thanks!